# What is a common, correct way to ask about improving a skill?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

For example, if I have difficulty listening, I might ask one of the following questions:

> 1. How to improve that?
> 2. How can I improve on that?
> 3. How do I improve on that?

Which of these questions is more correct to say in this situation?

I'd also be glad to know if any are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I think the natural phrasing would be, "How can I improve that?" or "How do I improve that?", or depending on context you might use a generic "you" and say, "How can you improve that?", etc.

Your versions 2 and 3 are grammatically correct. Version 1 is not correct because it has no subject. Who is doing the improving?

Comment: I use both 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

The first question, 'How to improve that?' is a sentence fragment; it's incomplete. Also, it's asking the wrong question. "How to improve that ... I have difficulty in listening" ? How to improve ... the difficulty? You want to know how to make it *more* difficult to listen? I would think what you want is to improve your listening, not the difficulty. But the word *that* is ambiguous in this phrase.

When you add the subject "I" and the preposition "on", as in "How can I improve on that?" You slightly improve the ambiguity. "How can I improve on ... I have difficulty in listening."

To be clear, you'd make a full sentence of something like "How can I improve my listening skills?" Or something similar, but if you need to use 'that', the latter two examples are fine.